# How to safely enlarge a gzipped file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gzip

I have a gzipped file (around 3Kb), and I want its size to be exactly 4000.

To achieve this goal, is it safe to add trailing padding with zeroes? (By safe I mean that the content of the gzipped file can be gunzipped without errors.)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/myfile bs=1 count=4000
dd if=/gzipfile.gz of=/myfile
```

If this is not safe, are there alternatives?

Comment: Why?  And you could simply try it and see.

Comment: I've tested with one file and it works; but I want to be sure that this process ALWAYS works.

Comment: It is safe in a sense, as the gzipped stream has the End-Of-Stream encoded in it, so if the code that expands the stream 'discards' whatever is appended then it is OK to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

> ```
> CAVEATS
>
>  When writing compressed data to a tape, it is generally
>  necessary to pad the output with zeroes up to a block
>  boundary. When the data is read and the whole block is
>  passed to gun‐ zip for decompression, gunzip detects that
>  there is extra trailing garbage after the compressed data
>  and emits a warning by default. You have to use the
>  --quiet option to suppress the warning.
> ```

So it would seem you're safe.

Note though that your code doesn't work, as you'd need to pass
`conv=notrunc` on the second `dd` invocation.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
dd bs=4000 seek=1 count=0 of=file.gz
```

or

```
truncate  -s 4000 file.gz
```

To make it 4000 bytes large (without actually writing zeros, just make it sparse).

Comment: A sparse file has _blocks_ of zeros, and if the file is almost 4KiB long, there isn't space for blocks at the end.